# .Net Git Library that allows for in memory addition / modification of files

Tags: c#, git, version-control

Does anyone know of a Git library for C# that allows client code to add & modify repository files in memory? I have a bare repository that I would like to make additions and modifications to pragmatically. Because it is a bare repository I do not want to write files to the file system. Does something like this exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GitSharp** exposes a **[`Create()`](https://github.com/henon/GitSharp/blob/master/GitSharp/Blob.cs#L142)** overload on its `Blob` type which allows a direct write to the Git Object database without the need for an intermediate file in a Working Directory.

The unit test below (slightly patched from **[BlobTests.cs](https://github.com/henon/GitSharp/blob/master/GitSharp.Tests/GitSharp/BlobTests.cs)**) demonstrates such feature:

```
[Test]
public void WriteBlob()
{
    using (var repo = GetTrashRepository())
    {
        blob = Blob.Create(repo, "and this is the data in me\r\n\r\n");
        Assert.AreEqual("95ea6a6859af6791464bd8b6de76ad5a6f9fad81", blob.Hash);

        var same_blob = new Blob(repo, blob.Hash);
        Assert.AreEqual(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("and this is the data in me\r\n\r\n"), same_blob.RawData);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

You might also be willing to take a look at **[NGit](https://github.com/slluis/ngit)**. It's an automated port of JGit to .Net. Contrarily to GitSharp, it is still maintained.

The `ObjectInserter` (see [here](https://github.com/slluis/ngit/blob/master/NGit/NGit/ObjectInserter.cs)) looks like **[something promising](https://github.com/slluis/ngit/blob/master/NGit.Test/NGit.Storage.File/T0003_BasicTest.cs#L731)**.

**Note:** If you're willing to use Git as an object database, by directly writing objects  without the Commit dance, make sure to create a reference (in `.git/refs`) to prevent them from being pruned upon a `git gc` launch.

**Note 2:** Git objects are read only, so you won't be able to "modify" a `Blob`. However, if you created a reference pointing at it, you can create a new "updated" `Blob`, and change the target of the reference to point at the new "version".

Answer (score 0):

A bare repository IS on the file system. If you would like some fast in-memory manipulation, use a ram disk. This way you still get the up-to-date functionality of git.